# looking for a way to join values in a set with(column B) when their corresponding values (column a), are the same, google. sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I need to add the numbers next to the comma separated initials to their relevant initials, and if they don't yet exist, I need to add them as new initials.

I have laid out all the information as it comes to me, and how i need it to look when its done,

It seems so damn simple, yet my brain at the moment is FAILING!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K5Ujj-pda6XFVEv1CBfmsQQTmeSBUygq5ayha39gv_A/edit#gid=0

ANY help would be very much appreciated.

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula may help you:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(split(flatten(split(if(A2:A<>"",SUBSTITUTE(A2:A," ","")," "),",")&","&B2:B),",",,FALSE),"select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null and Col1 <>' ' group by Col1 label sum(Col2)'' "))`

The problem is that the original sorting of the elements is broken. Query sorts alphabetically when using Group By.

[image]

Comment: Nice, Sergey. It can also be shortened a bit this way: =ArrayFormula(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A,","))&"~"&B2:B),"~"),"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL SUM(Col2) ''"))

Comment: omg, what a great solution, thankyou very much, even looking at this now, I never would have thought about this method, but I CAN understand how this works.

THANKYOU so much.